# MongoDB Delete query perform not in database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Please help me. How to design a schema & perform delete query. But data not deleted permanently. But the user feels like their data is deleted.

Comment: You are talking about the soft delete. It must be implemented in the application layer (data model / ORM), not DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongoosejs Soft Delete Plugin

For that, you need to use `mongoosejs` plugin first and then add `mongoosejs-soft-delete` plugin to your schema.

You can find the example on the following link.

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosejs-soft-delete